# "MissingMethodException: Method not found" но аналогичные методы в этом же скрипте работают

Tags: c#, unity3d

Создаю игру на Unity с использованием новой InputSystem. Создал несколько аналогичных методов при нажатии нужных кнопок. Они работают. Но новый, практически ничем не отличающийся, на ровном месте выдаёт ошибку:

```
MissingMethodException: Method 'PlayerController.OnCursorActivating' not found.
System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember (System.String name, System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object target, System.Object[] providedArgs, System.Reflection.ParameterModifier[] modifiers, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, System.String[] namedParams) (at <dc753a1061284f8e971ee88ee4826eee>:0)
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMember (System.Object behaviour, System.String name, System.Object variable) (at <6f7018b8b8c149e68c4a65a05ac289be>:0)
UnityEngine.InputSystem.LowLevel.<>c__DisplayClass7_0:<set_onUpdate>b__0(NativeInputUpdateType, NativeInputEventBuffer*)
UnityEngineInternal.Input.NativeInputSystem:NotifyUpdate(NativeInputUpdateType, IntPtr)
```

Вот скрипт PlayerController:

```
[SerializeField] private InputActionAsset _inputActionAsset;
[SerializeField] MainCharacterActions _currentCharacter;
private InputActionMap _playerMap;
private InputAction _attackAction;
private InputAction _cursorActivating;

private void Awake()
{
    _playerMap = _inputActionAsset.FindActionMap("Player");
    _attackAction = _playerMap.FindAction("Attack");
    _cursorActivating = _playerMap.FindAction("CursorActivating");
}

private void OnEnable()
{
    _playerMap.Enable();
    _attackAction.performed += OnAttackInput;
    _cursorActivating.performed += OnCursorActivating;
}
private void OnDisable()
{
    _playerMap.Disable();
    _attackAction.performed -= OnAttackInput;
    _cursorActivating.performed -= OnCursorActivating;
}

private void OnAttackInput(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
{
    _currentCharacter.PlayerComboAttack();
}
private void OnCursorActivating(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
{
    CursorVisibilityChange();
}

public void CursorVisibilityChange()
{
    Debug.Log("работает");
}
```

Имена методов проверил, названия экшнов в инпутах тоже. Не знаю что не так. Но при этом метод `CursorVisibilityChange()` вызываемый внутри выдающего ошибку `OnCursorActivating` работает как надо

Comment: Пробовали [это](https://forum.unity.com/threads/missingmethodexception-method-not-found.1337873/)?